# Trying to install MotionBuilder, but using alien to convert from rpm isn't working

Tags: software-installation, deb, rpm, alien

When I start the `./setup` command I am taken to the proper installation medium, but after agreeing to terms the installer says that I need to alien the files. Needless to say this hasn't worked so far. Alien runs fine, but the installer won't recognize the files. When trying to install using `apt install` on the file after I alien the rpm I get:

```
    apt install ./motionbuilder2020-64_2020-2_amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'motionbuilder2020-64' instead of './motionbuilder2020-64_2020-2_amd64.deb'
The following packages will be upgraded:
  motionbuilder2020-64
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/598 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2,246 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 /home/cole/Downloads/MotionBuilder/motionbuilder2020-64_2020-2_amd64.deb motionbuilder2020-64 amd64 2020-2 [598 MB]
(Reading database ... 215608 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../motionbuilder2020-64_2020-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking motionbuilder2020-64 (2020-2) over (2020-2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /home/cole/Downloads/MotionBuilder/motionbuilder2
020-64_2020-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/var/opt/Autodesk/Adlm/ASR/ENCSU202000F_EL_Adlm.asr', whic
h is also in package maya2020-64 2020.0-236
Native call error in adlmPITRemoveProductInformation_2 12: The root information 
in PIT XML file is missing
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 new motionbuilder2020-64 package post-removal script subprocess returned error 
exit status 12
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/cole/Downloads/MotionBuilder/motionbuilder2020-64_2020-2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@cole-desktop:/home/cole/Downloads/MotionBuilder# ./setup
bash: ./setup: No such file or directory
```

I've been struggling with this for a while now, so any help would be much appreciated! [image]
Edit: this software requires that I input a licence, skipping this won't allow it to run.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in above command output is

> `dpkg: error processing archive /home/cole/Downloads/MotionBuilder/motionbuilder2
> 020-64_2020-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
>
> trying to overwrite '/var/opt/Autodesk/Adlm/ASR/ENCSU202000F_EL_Adlm.asr', whic
> h is also in package maya2020-64 2020.0-236`

To overcome it you have to backup problematic file with

```
cp /var/opt/Autodesk/Adlm/ASR/ENCSU202000F_EL_Adlm.asr ~
```

and then force installation of failing deb-package with

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /home/cole/Downloads/MotionBuilder/motionbuilder2020-64_2020-2_amd64.deb
```

and then fix possible dependency issues with

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: That kind of worked. It did install the application, but I am unable to open it, really just an icon as of now. Running the ./setup command also still gives me the same msg about rpm. In case this might be confusing, the MotionBuilder folder is one I made to try and separate it from the rest of the Downloads. I'm not sure what downloads came with motionbuilder, so that's why I haven't just deleted them and tried fresh. I'm not sure, but I think what might be happening is that it isn't recognizing the license since it may have skipped that step. How do I check/fix this?